# Joomla Menu image not displaying

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, menu-parameters

Joomla menu image is not displaying on website. I believe I have it configured correctly but is not displaying.

Here is my configuration:

[image: Config]

Here is what is displayed on the website:

[image: Menu]

Here is what I'm trying to make my menu look like:

[image: Example]

The file path exists and I can see the image in the media tab in Joomla and CPanel.

The path is `/images/Visual-Studio-Logo.png`.

When I inspect the element of the menu button, there is no mention of the image.

```
<a class="item" href="insert link here">Visual Studio </a>
```

My SE account is fully verified, what mightve happened is I made this post on a guest account then verified it after.

Yes I see the difference between the 2 names that was a typo as I've just confirmed they are matching.

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for asking a question.  Please take our [tour]. How about the existence of the file at that location?  Do you see the file in your filesystem?  What is the path to the file?

Comment: So is this a case-sensitivity issue?  When you right click the failed image element in your browser and Inspect Element, what is in the `src` value of the img tag?

Comment: I don't know why you are not instantly allowed to [edit] your own question (you shouldn't need your edits to be approved by the community when it is your own question).  Something is weird.  Did you verify your JSE account?  Please take our [tour].  You can see the difference between `visual-studio-logo.png` and `Visual-Studio-Logo.png`, right?

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to give you clear instructions, but you should "merge" your two accounts (which seem to have the same name) so that you  can edit your own question without approval.  I cannot do this task.  You will have to make this request of paid employees of the Stack Overflow corporation.

Comment: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts